# Do I need to learn python first to understand the part 2 of the book Test Driven development?

Tags: java, python, unit-testing, tdd

It seems like Python is used as a coding language for part 2 of Kent Beck's book [Test Driven Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321146530). I have read the first part of that book and started appreciating the value of TDD . First part was easy to understand as the examples were in Java and that is the only language that I have worked on. How should I prepare myself to go about reading the second part of the book? What value will it provide? I do not plan to write a testing framework myself. Can I skip this entirely and go to the third section?

Comment: Python is the closest you can get to executable pseudo-code. Beck includes a primer on the language fundamentals; why not try reading on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters What do you mean by executable pseudo-code and how is it relevant in this case?

Comment: I was quoting [Bruce Eckel](http://mindview.net/Books/Python/ThinkingInPython.html); Pseudo code is the stuff you write on the blackboard when teaching a algorithm class where you are not focusing on the code syntax but on what the code is doing. Python is *extremely readable*, if you know general programming you'll understand most Python code.

Comment: If you're really confused or concerned about the second portion of that book, I suggest you read this excellent alternative (first/instead): [Test Driven: TDD and Acceptance TDD for Java Developers](http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Acceptance-Java-Developers/dp/1932394850/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everybody should learn more than one language.

Python is a great language widely used to illustrate programming concepts such as 'Cognitive Intelligence', 'Semantic Web', 'Natural language processing' to name just 3 O'Reilly titles.

Learning a little Python will make you a better Java programmer .

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not mandatory to know the language used in books to get the ideas behind that. If you're interested anyways, feel free to learn it. But it's not that important. The **concepts** matter.